# How to darken the Canvas or the Image drawn on a Canvas?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I derived the `Canvas` class where in the `paint` method I draw an `Image`. When clicking a `Command` I want to draw in the Canvas a rectangle and a String inside the rectangle , and the Image will still be displayed behind the rectangle, so I want to darken a bit the Image because I want to make a visual effect like the one when showing LWUIT Dialog ( the tint color of the hidden Form ). So how to darken a bit the canvas in this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that width and height of image are known, I'd probably first use use [Image.getRGB](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#getRGB%28int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to get ARGB values for image pixels.

Then, I'd scale the RGB values to make an effect of it becoming darker.

```
int[] darken(int[] argb, int percentage) {
    int[] result = new int[argb.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <argb.length; i++) {
        result[i] = darkenArgb(argb[i], percentage);
    }
    return result;
}

private int darkenArgb(int argb, int percentage) {
    return darkenByte(argb, 3, 100) // keep alpha as-is
            | darkenByte(argb, 2, percentage)
            | darkenByte(argb, 1, percentage)
            | darkenByte(argb, 0, percentage);
}

private int darkenByte(int argb, int index, int percentage) {
    if (percentage < 0 || percentage > 100) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected percentage: ["
               + percentage + "]");
    }
    if (index < 0 || index > 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected index: [" + index + "]");
    }
    int result = (argb >> index) & 0xFF;
    result = result * percentage / 100;
    return result << index;
}
```

From an array obtained with `darken` method, darkened image could be made using [Image.createRGBImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html#createRGBImage%28int%5b%5d,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: What should be the value of `percentage` in the method `darken` ?

Comment: @pheromix that one you'd have to find out by experimenting. I'd try at least 25, 50 and 75 to test how it feels